# Nexus repository auto update

Tags: maven, svn, repository, nexus

Is there any way to configure Nexus to update uploaded artifact after it has been changed and committed to Subversion? For example, I have made some changes to the library I am working on, and I have deployed the jar file again and want to update the artifact that is installed in nexus already? is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Start using a contious integration solution like Jenkins; Start a build by a change in SVN and run the build and if sucessfull deploy artifacts to Nexus.

Comment: Be aware that you can (normally) update SNAPSHOT artifacts only. If you have release versions take a look at the maven-release-plugin to automatically handle version numbers.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have already installed TeamCity, is it ok? Or only jenkins?

Comment: TeamCity is also ok if you like to pay money for the license. Jenkins is free without a license fee. Both can do the job.